# How to pass parameter of API route to attribute validation

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, routes, attributes

I am trying to use an API route parameter (which will be used in multiple APIs) to be able to pass along to a validation attribute.

This would be the attribute

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All)]
public class AuthorizeSheetOwnerAttribute : Attribute
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext context;
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor;

    public int characterSheetId { get; set; }

    public AuthorizeSheetOwnerAttribute(int characterSheetId, ApplicationDbContext context, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        this.characterSheetId = characterSheetId;
        this.context = context;
        this.httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    public async Task<bool> IsOwnerAsync()
    {
        var userId = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
        if (context.CharacterSheetModel.FirstOrDefault(c => c.UserId == userId && c.Id == characterSheetId) == null) return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

This would be the implimentation

```
[Route("api/{characterSheetId}/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
[AuthorizeSheetOwner(characterSheetId = "{characterSheetId}")]
public class WorldController : ControllerBase
{
```

The attribute should take the characterSheetId coming in from the route to populate the attribute property but I'm not sure how I can do that... I admit to being a little naive on the attribute handling side of things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize a action filter that inherits `ActionFilterAttribute` and use it as a attribute on the controller . Directly read the route data in `OnActionExecuting` event like :

```
public class AuthorizeSheetOwnerAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var characterSheetId = filterContext.RouteData.Values["characterSheetId"].ToString() ;

        //write your logic


        if (false)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult("Custom error");
        } 

    }
}
```

Usage :

```
[Route("api/{characterSheetId}/[controller]")]
[AuthorizeSheetOwner]
[ApiController]
```

Comment: Is there an async method that does the equivalent? I will be calling to the database during validation and do not want to hold up other services. This does seem like it is what i'm looking for though

Comment: you can use `IAsyncActionFilter` , see code sample : https://code-maze.com/action-filters-aspnetcore/ and document : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.2#implementation

Comment: The answer was a mixture between what you provided in the answer and the first code sample. You can not do DI very easily with the above option. Thank you very much!